# How to convert 'module type' with 'non-generic type' to 'module type' with 'generic type' by destructive substitution?

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I have a module type with three non-generic types:

```
module type LAYER = sig
  type cytoplasm_t
  type nucleus_t
  type t

  val cytoplasm        : int -> t -> cytoplasm_t
  val nucleus          : int -> t -> nucleus_t 

  val add_cytoplasm    : int -> cytoplasm_t -> t -> t
  val add_nucleus      : int -> nucleus_t -> t -> t
  val remove_cytoplasm : int -> t -> t
  val remove_nucleus   : int -> t -> t
end
```

I want to convert it to a module type with a generic nested type that has two type parameters instead of two non-generic types as it is in the source module type:

```
module type LAYER' = sig
  type ('cytoplasm, 'nucleus) t

  val cytoplasm        : int -> ('c, 'n) t -> 'c
  val nucleus          : int -> ('c, 'n) t -> 'n 

  val add_cytoplasm    : int -> 'c -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
  val add_nucleus      : int -> 'n -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
  val remove_cytoplasm : int -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
  val remove_nucleus   : int -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
end
```

I tried to do that by 'include' with ':=' but failed:

```
module type LAYER' = sig
  type ('c, 'n) t
  
  include LAYER 
     with type t := ('c, 'n) t
      and type nucleus_t := 'n
      and type cytoplasm_t := 'c
end
```

> Error: The type variable 'c is unbound in this type declaration

As I expected, destructive substitution doesn't work like replacement.  I have a long list of functions in my real-life example, and this feature would be helpful for me. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot replace a type of a given arity with an implementation of another arity.

Why not becomes clearer when we make the arities and the *binders* of type variables more explicit than in basic ML syntax, where they are left implicit.

With some made-up syntax, your first signature then becomes:

```ml
module type LAYER =
sig
  type t : 0
  type cytoplasm_t : 0
  type nucleus_t : 0
  val cytoplasm : int -> t -> cytoplasm_t
  val add_cytoplasm : int -> cytoplasm_t -> t -> t
  ...
end
```

while your second is:

```ml
module type LAYER' =
sig
  type t : 2
  type cytoplasm_t = ???
  type nucleus_t = ???
  val cytoplasm : forall ('c, 'n). int -> ('c, 'n) t -> 'c
  val add_cytoplasm : forall ('c, 'n). int -> 'c -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
  ...
end
```

If the replacement you want was allowed: (1) what would the binders for `'c` and `'n` in types `cytoplasm_t` and `nucleus_t` be? (2) where would the `forall` for them come from for value `cytoplasm`? And (3), why is it correct to assume that all occurrences of `t` for `add_cytoplasm` share the same arguments — it could just as well become one of these:

```ml
val add_cytoplasm : forall ('c1, 'n1, 'c2, 'n2). int -> 'c1 -> ('c1, 'n1) t -> ('c2, 'n2) t
val add_cytoplasm : forall ('c1, 'n1, 'c2, 'n2). int -> 'c2 -> ('c1, 'n1) t -> ('c2, 'n2) t
```

---

Now to answer your question practically, the only solution is to do it the other way round: the original signature must anticipate the most polymorphic usage. Then you can make it *less* polymorphic by replacement. For example:

```ml
module type LAYER' =
sig
  type ('c, 'n) t
  type ('c, 'n) cytoplasm_t
  type ('c, 'n) nucleus_t
  val cytoplasm : int -> ('c, 'n) t -> 'c
  val add_cytoplasm : int -> 'c -> ('c, 'n) t -> ('c, 'n) t
  ...
end

module type LAYER =
sig
  type t
  include LAYER'
    with type ('c, 'n) t := t
    with type ('c, 'n) cytoplasm_t := 'c
    with type ('c, 'n) nucleus_t := 'n
end
```

This way, you make explicit where all the binders are, and the replacement later just makes some of them redundant.